# Python - How to get number of teams under a manager using manager hierarchy columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, hierarchy

I have a dataframe with the employee emails, manager emails and the manager hierarchy columns. Am trying to get the number of teams that a manager has.

My current dataframe

```
emp_email        mgr_email       mgr_hier_01    mgr_hier_02     mgr_hier_03            
jack@abc.com     cook@abc.com    CEO@abc.com    sandy@abc.com   cook@abc.com     
katy@abc.com     cook@abc.com    CEO@abc.com    sandy@abc.com   cook@abc.com     
panko@abc.com    jacob@abc.com   CEO@abc.com    jacob@abc.com
lynne@abc.com    jacob@abc.com   CEO@abc.com    jacob@abc.com                                       
tom@abc.com      brian@abc.com   CEO@abc.com    livp@abc.com    brian@abc.com    
grace@abc.com    noah@abc.com    CEO@abc.com    noah@abc.com                     
will@abc.com     hugh@abc.com    CEO@abc.com    hugh@abc.com                     
samson@abc.com   sheila@abc.com  CEO@abc.com    noah@abc.com    sheila@abc.com   
johnson@abc.com  nick@abc.com    CEO@abc.com    nick@abc.com                     
pete@abc.com     jody@abc.com    CEO@abc.com    livp@abc.com    jody@abc.com     
torres@abc.com   golio@abc.com   CEO@abc.com    sandy@abc.com   golio@abc.com    
jody@abc.com     livp@abc.com    CEO@abc.com    livp@abc.com                                    
sandy@abc.com    CEO@abc.com     CEO@abc.com                                     
jacob@abc.com    CEO@abc.com     CEO@abc.com                                     
cook@abc.com     sandy@abc.com   CEO@abc.com    sandy@abc.com                    
livp@abc.com     CEO@abc.com     CEO@abc.com                                     
noah@abc.com     CEO@abc.com     CEO@abc.com                                     
hugh@abc.com     CEO@abc.com     CEO@abc.com                                     
brian@abc.com    livp@abc.com    CEO@abc.com    livp@abc.com                      
nick@abc.com     CEO@abc.com     CEO@abc.com                                     
sheila@abc.com   noah@abc.com    CEO@abc.com    noah@abc.com
golio@abc.com    sandy@abc.com   CEO@abc.com    sandy@abc.com                    
CEO@abc.com      NAN             NAN
```

what I hope to achieve is a column which gives the counts of number of teams a manager has if the employee is a manager. For example, sandy@abc.com has 2 managers reporting to her (cook@abc.com and golio@abc.com) so the count of teams under her should be 2. While jacob@abc.com has no managers reporting to him but he is a manager managing 2 individual contributors (panko@abc.com and lynne@abc.com). So the count of teams under jacob@abc.com should be 1.

```
emp_email        mgr_email       mgr_hier_01    mgr_hier_02     mgr_hier_03      num_teams_if_mgr     
jack@abc.com     cook@abc.com    CEO@abc.com    sandy@abc.com   cook@abc.com     0
katy@abc.com     cook@abc.com    CEO@abc.com    sandy@abc.com   cook@abc.com     0
panko@abc.com    jacob@abc.com   CEO@abc.com    jacob@abc.com                    0
lynne@abc.com    jacob@abc.com   CEO@abc.com    jacob@abc.com                    0
tom@abc.com      brian@abc.com   CEO@abc.com    livp@abc.com    brian@abc.com    0
grace@abc.com    noah@abc.com    CEO@abc.com    noah@abc.com                     0
will@abc.com     hugh@abc.com    CEO@abc.com    hugh@abc.com                     0
samson@abc.com   sheila@abc.com  CEO@abc.com    noah@abc.com    sheila@abc.com   0
johnson@abc.com  nick@abc.com    CEO@abc.com    nick@abc.com                     0
pete@abc.com     jody@abc.com   CEO@abc.com    livp@abc.com    jody@abc.com     0
torres@abc.com   golio@abc.com   CEO@abc.com    sandy@abc.com   golio@abc.com    0
jody@abc.com     livp@abc.com    CEO@abc.com    livp@abc.com                     1                
sandy@abc.com    CEO@abc.com     CEO@abc.com                                     2
jacob@abc.com    CEO@abc.com     CEO@abc.com                                     1
cook@abc.com     sandy@abc.com   CEO@abc.com    sandy@abc.com                    1
livp@abc.com     CEO@abc.com     CEO@abc.com                                     2
noah@abc.com     CEO@abc.com     CEO@abc.com                                     1
hugh@abc.com     CEO@abc.com     CEO@abc.com                                     1 
brian@abc.com    livp@abc.com    CEO@abc.com    livp@abc.com                     1  
nick@abc.com     CEO@abc.com     CEO@abc.com                                     1
sheila@abc.com   noah@abc.com    CEO@abc.com    noah@abc.com                     1  
golio@abc.com    sandy@abc.com   CEO@abc.com    sandy@abc.com                    1
CEO@abc.com      NAN             NAN                                             6
```

So far, I am only able to create the hierarchy columns for the dataframe with the code below. Appreciate any form of assistance.

```
import networkx as nx

# create graph
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df_hc, source='mgr_email', target='emp_email', create_using=nx.DiGraph)

# find roots (= top managers)
roots = [n for n,d in G.in_degree() if d==0]

# for each employee, find the hierarchy 
df_hierarchy = (pd.DataFrame([next((p for root in roots for p in nx.all_simple_paths(G, root, node)), [])[:-1] for node in df_hc['emp_email']], index= df_hc.index).rename(columns=lambda x: f'mgr_hier_{x+1:02d}'))

# join to original DataFrame
df_hc2 = df_hc.join(df_hierarchy)
```

Comment: There seems to be an inconsistency for `torres@abc.com` where their `mgr_email` is `sandy@abc.com` but they have an entry in `mgr_hier_03` which is `golio@abc.com`?

Comment: @Nick thanks for spotting that

Comment: @wjie08 did this ever solved your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand your concept of teams, but assuming a team is more than one person, then count the descendants that are not leafs:

```
leafs = {n for n,d in G.out_degree() if d==0}
d = {n: len(nx.descendants_at_distance(G, n, 1)-leafs)
     for n in G.nodes}
df_hc['num_teams_if_mgr'] = df_hc['emp_email'].map(d)
```

Output:

```
          emp_email       mgr_email  mgr_hier_01    mgr_hier_02     mgr_hier_03  num_teams_if_mgr
0      jack@abc.com    cook@abc.com  CEO@abc.com  sandy@abc.com    cook@abc.com                 0
1      katy@abc.com    cook@abc.com  CEO@abc.com  sandy@abc.com    cook@abc.com                 0
2     panko@abc.com   jacob@abc.com  CEO@abc.com  jacob@abc.com            None                 0
3     lynne@abc.com   jacob@abc.com  CEO@abc.com  jacob@abc.com            None                 0
4       tom@abc.com   brian@abc.com  CEO@abc.com   livp@abc.com   brian@abc.com                 0
5     grace@abc.com    noah@abc.com  CEO@abc.com   noah@abc.com            None                 0
6      will@abc.com    hugh@abc.com  CEO@abc.com   hugh@abc.com            None                 0
7    samson@abc.com  sheila@abc.com  CEO@abc.com   noah@abc.com  sheila@abc.com                 0
8   johnson@abc.com    nick@abc.com  CEO@abc.com   nick@abc.com            None                 0
9      pete@abc.com   brian@abc.com  CEO@abc.com   livp@abc.com    jody@abc.com                 0
10   torres@abc.com   sandy@abc.com  CEO@abc.com  sandy@abc.com   golio@abc.com                 0
11     jody@abc.com    livp@abc.com  CEO@abc.com   livp@abc.com            None                 0
12    sandy@abc.com     CEO@abc.com  CEO@abc.com           None            None                 1
13    jacob@abc.com     CEO@abc.com  CEO@abc.com           None            None                 0
14     cook@abc.com   sandy@abc.com  CEO@abc.com  sandy@abc.com            None                 0
15     livp@abc.com     CEO@abc.com  CEO@abc.com           None            None                 1
16     noah@abc.com     CEO@abc.com  CEO@abc.com           None            None                 1
17     hugh@abc.com     CEO@abc.com  CEO@abc.com           None            None                 0
18    brian@abc.com    livp@abc.com  CEO@abc.com   livp@abc.com            None                 0
19     nick@abc.com     CEO@abc.com  CEO@abc.com           None            None                 0
20   sheila@abc.com    noah@abc.com  CEO@abc.com   noah@abc.com            None                 0
21    golio@abc.com   sandy@abc.com  CEO@abc.com  sandy@abc.com            None                 0
22      CEO@abc.com             NAN          NAN           None            None                 6
```

If you want to count +1 if the employee is itself not a leaf:

```
leafs = {n for n,d in G.out_degree() if d==0}
d = {n: len(nx.descendants_at_distance(G, n, 1)-leafs)
        + (not n in leafs) for n in G.nodes}
df_hc['num_teams_if_mgr'] = df_hc['emp_email'].map(d)
```

Output:

```
          emp_email       mgr_email  mgr_hier_01    mgr_hier_02     mgr_hier_03  num_teams_if_mgr
0      jack@abc.com    cook@abc.com  CEO@abc.com  sandy@abc.com    cook@abc.com                 0
1      katy@abc.com    cook@abc.com  CEO@abc.com  sandy@abc.com    cook@abc.com                 0
2     panko@abc.com   jacob@abc.com  CEO@abc.com  jacob@abc.com            None                 0
3     lynne@abc.com   jacob@abc.com  CEO@abc.com  jacob@abc.com            None                 0
4       tom@abc.com   brian@abc.com  CEO@abc.com   livp@abc.com   brian@abc.com                 0
5     grace@abc.com    noah@abc.com  CEO@abc.com   noah@abc.com            None                 0
6      will@abc.com    hugh@abc.com  CEO@abc.com   hugh@abc.com            None                 0
7    samson@abc.com  sheila@abc.com  CEO@abc.com   noah@abc.com  sheila@abc.com                 0
8   johnson@abc.com    nick@abc.com  CEO@abc.com   nick@abc.com            None                 0
9      pete@abc.com   brian@abc.com  CEO@abc.com   livp@abc.com    jody@abc.com                 0
10   torres@abc.com   sandy@abc.com  CEO@abc.com  sandy@abc.com   golio@abc.com                 0
11     jody@abc.com    livp@abc.com  CEO@abc.com   livp@abc.com            None                 0
12    sandy@abc.com     CEO@abc.com  CEO@abc.com           None            None                 2
13    jacob@abc.com     CEO@abc.com  CEO@abc.com           None            None                 1
14     cook@abc.com   sandy@abc.com  CEO@abc.com  sandy@abc.com            None                 1
15     livp@abc.com     CEO@abc.com  CEO@abc.com           None            None                 2
16     noah@abc.com     CEO@abc.com  CEO@abc.com           None            None                 2
17     hugh@abc.com     CEO@abc.com  CEO@abc.com           None            None                 1
18    brian@abc.com    livp@abc.com  CEO@abc.com   livp@abc.com            None                 1
19     nick@abc.com     CEO@abc.com  CEO@abc.com           None            None                 1
20   sheila@abc.com    noah@abc.com  CEO@abc.com   noah@abc.com            None                 1
21    golio@abc.com   sandy@abc.com  CEO@abc.com  sandy@abc.com            None                 0
22      CEO@abc.com             NAN          NAN           None            None                 7
```

Graph:

[image]